# How to kill process started by a service on Windows 2000 Server?

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2000

I need to kill a process on a Windows 2000 production server, which was started by a windows service. However, doing that from the GUI just gives me "Access denied", so now I am considering to create a small application or script to do it. I only have occasionally access to the GUI, I do not have usernames, passwords etc. for the server. Any ideas?

Comment: What "GUI" are you using? You need to logon as a local administrator to be able to kill processes started with another account.

Comment: kill.exe [which is build in TTBOMK] would achieve the same as your app you propose writing, if you actually have the rights in the first place.

Comment: See also serverfault.com

Comment: Or use pskill (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) which allows you to kill processes remotely given you provide credentials having the required privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Some services run as system and you need to escalate to the system user in order ot kill it. I would recommend looking into system internals to find a way to help you achieve what you are looking for.